# Extending a directive and adding to the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I been trying to figure this issue out, looking throughout S.O and other sites, but I can not figure it out. I'm still new to Angular, so I can't grasp the concept of it. I hope someone can answer my own problem and try to help me understand.

I'm trying to modify a 3rd party directive and add a `<button>` that will later on trigger a function in Angular. I need to somehow extend this directive and add it.

The directive: https://github.com/irontec/angular-bootstrap-simple-chat

I'm not entirely sure where to begin or what code to even give out. I'm pretty much just using the default code on the page.

How can I do this?

EDIT: I'm not sure how to modify my app.js and use the below answer in my code (app.js, below snippet):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('sg',
  ['sg.Directives.Popover',
  'sg.Directives.ToggleClass',
  'sg.MainCtrl',
  'sg.NavCtrl',
  'sg.DepositCtrl',
  'sg.Services',
  'ui.router',
  'firebase',
  'angular-svg-round-progress',
  'irontec.simpleChat'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          '': {
          templateUrl: 'js/template/main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          },
          'nav': {
            templateUrl: 'js/template/nav.html',
            controller: 'NavCtrl'
          }
        }
      });
  }])
  .filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.slice().reverse();
  };
});
```

How can I make my code work with the below answer?

Comment: Can't you wrap this directive in another directive?

Comment: Example? I'm not totally understanding how that would work? @miparnisari

Answer (score 1):

So this is where decorators come in to help, take a look at the working example here **http://plnkr.co/edit/hzp0waR03npsS1PVrr4c?p=preview**

All you need to do is gran the directive at the config phase and make the changes you need

```
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('irontecSimpleChatDirective', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];

    console.log(directive);
    directive.template = '<div>'+ directive.template +'<button>my button</button></div>'
    return $delegate; 
  });
});
```

Here I just threw the button at the very end, but you can add it where you need. Probably use regex instead of being as lazy as me. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! Where exactly do I add this in? In the site I have (which was built before the client hired me) there is a controller, directive, and services directive + an app.js. Also, how do I run angular code when clicking the button?

Comment: i would recommend doing it in the app.js file as it is in config phase.

Comment: you need to inject it after `$urlRouterProvider` as well, you only have it in the function right now.

Comment: That's what I thought bnut I'm getting this: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e%20%3C-NaNrontecSimpleChatDirective

http://i.imgur.com/8lSL4Ys.png